# In VSCode, is it possible to run the Command Palette's "Restart TS Server" command (or any other integrated command) using a shell or npm script?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

We have some codegen features in our project that generate typescript code used by the main application.  Whenever we run the codegen, we've found that the changes are often not detected by the IDE until we run the "Restart TS Server" command in the Command Palette.

Is there a way to incorporate that functionality in the yarn script that runs the codegen (or in a shell script we can reference from that script)?

Comment: What if someone uses another IDE and it doesn't work there as well? Then you need another script to restart it there?

Comment: That may be the case. However, if you standardize the toolset within the organization, then you'd still get good value even from a script that cannot be used with a different IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The [Remote Control extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.vscode-remote-control) [from Elio Struyf](https://github.com/estruyf/vscode-remote-control) and [websocat](https://docs.rs/crate/websocat) let you control VS Code via websockets.

The extension will automatically open a websocket on port 3710 by default. It announces this with *Remote Control: Listening on "ws://127.0.0.1:3170"* in the snackbar and a permanent indicator in the Status Bar:

[image: Snackbar message and Status Bar indicator]

You can then execute commands remotely by sending JSON messages to this websocket. For example via the CLI utility websocat:

```bash
echo "{ \"command\": \"typescript.restartTsServer\" }" | websocat ws://localhost:3710
```